# Solution of $Connect4^{TM}$

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory, pigeonhole-principle

It says here that [Connect4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four) can be won by Player $1$ if their first counter goes in the middle column $4$, a draw if they play in columns $3$ or $5$, and Player $1$ loses everywhere else.

As far as I can see, according to the wikipedia article, they cannot win before the $41^{st}$ move, I assume by the Pigeonhole Principle, which makes me think the board size was pre-determined by this fact.

Or can they win before the $41^{st}$ move?

ADDENDUM

There are $\dbinom{42}{21}=538,257,874,440$ final positions. Of course, many are 'game over' before they are realized, and several are impossible. Bonus question: how many complete Connect4 grids have no line of $4$?

Comment: It's usually known as an ***addendum***, not an *appendum*. :)